# Managing MappedColumnType conversions in a slick 3 project

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to build custom database column converters for a new Slick 3 project. It's pretty easy to make these using the MappedColumnType, but you have to have imported the driver api. For a one-off type in a single DAO class, this is straight forward. But I would like to use my custom column types across all my DAO objects. I have been unable to construct my import in a way that the compiler can recognize the implicits.

Here is an example of the type of library I would like to construct. It has a single converter, very similar to the ubiquitous Joda date converter seen in many Slick 2 examples.

```scala
package dao

import java.sql.Date

import data.Timestamp
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

case class StandardConversions(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  implicit val timestampColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Timestamp, Date](
    { data => new Date(data.value) },
    { sql => Timestamp(sql.getTime) }
  )

}
```

In the DAO class I try doing the import like this:

```scala
val conversions = StandardConversions(dbConfigProvider)
import conversions._
```

The compiler error is the familiar:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[data.Timestamp]
```

I'm basically stuck in dependency injection, implicit hell. Has anybody come up with a good way to maintain their custom conversions in Slick 3? Please share.

Comment: I suggest to add play framework tags too since you are using slick in conjunction with play.

Answer (score 2):

This is where traits come in handy:

```
package dao

import java.sql.Date
import data.Timestamp

import play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

trait StandardConversions extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  implicit val timestampColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Timestamp, Date](
    { data => new Date(data.value) },
    { sql => Timestamp(sql.getTime) }
  )
}
```

And then simply extend from this trait in your DAOs:

```
class SomeDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]
  with StandardConversions {

  import driver.api._

  // all implicits of StandardConversions are in scope here
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I tried it and it doesn't work. The problem seems to be that the implicit val doesn't get pulled into the with-class scope. Maybe I messed it up somehow. I'll confirm again....

Comment: Confirmed that this doesn't work. I get the error: `could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[data.Timestamp]`.

Comment: @Chris: Hmm not sure what exactly the problem is here... The code above is similar to the approach I'm using in my projects. Does the implicit conversion work if you put it directly into a DAO?

Comment: It does work when I move the implicit to the DAO. I wonder if it has to do with the specific database that I'm using, postgresql. I'll try switching to H2 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Chris: I doubt it is the db. Could you provide some more code including the slick table definition?

Answer (score 0):

In combination with Roman's solution, you should probably add the following import:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```